# Jquery $(this).prop('selectedIndex', num) not working

Tags: jquery, selectedindex

The line of code mentioned above does work usually, but not when I move it into the function (data) return from my php script. I'm assuming something is out of scope or something like that? Here's the code, stripped down to the basics.

```
$('.training_staff_change').on('change',
    function () {

        // Post the data.
        $.post('updatetrainingstaff.php',
            {
            } ,
        function ( data ) {
            $(this).prop('selectedIndex', 5);   
        }
        )
});
```

As I say, that's stripped down, the rest of the code is working fine. If I move the line out of the function and below the ) it works fine and sets the selector as required. Is $(this) out of scope here or something?    In my final code, it will change the selectedIndex to the 'data' return value, but that's not the issue here. It won't even change it to a straight '5'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's out of scope (you self-answer your question), but to solve this there are so many ways, the simplest way is this:

```
$('.training_staff_change').on('change',
    function () {
        var that = $(this);
        // Post the data.
        $.post('updatetrainingstaff.php',
            {
            } ,
        function ( data ) {
            that.prop('selectedIndex', 5);   
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: Thanks. And thanks for that solution, nice and simple. I'll go and read up on why that's out of scope because it looks in scope to me, since it's all in the same function?

Comment: No, because when you create a new function (where the selectedIndex sentence is in) you change the scope to that. In your example, the scope of `$(this)` is the `$.post()` method, instead the `on()` method

Comment: Oh cool, I get it, thanks. For some reason I thought scope went down into new functions, but I can see now that it doesn't. Thanks, I'll be marking yours as the accepted answer in a few minutes (it's telling me to wait a few more minutes before I can accept).

Comment: No exactly. The new function creation doesn't neccesary change the scope. Think in a vanilla object like `var obj = function() { var prop = "yeah"; var method = function() { console.log(this.prop);}; }` The scope inside `method()` is the `obj` object

Comment: Gotcha. At least if I get stuck on this again, I'll know that I can try saving $this into a variable. For some reason I didn't realise that I could do that, it's kinda obvious now :)

Comment: yes, you can conserve the refference for future use. There are more ways more efficient and more "proffesional", but in this simple case the best way is the simplest way. Good luck!